# Must Declare Scalar variable C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have only just started using SQL Server in C# but I am getting an error

> Must Declare Scalar Variable

when it tries to run. Obviously I have read other posts where this was the problem and I have tried to fix it using the information from the posts, however none were successful.

```
public static void AddUser(ProgressBar progressBar1, string FirstName, string LastName, string CurrentWorkingGrade, string PredictedGrade, string year)
{
    try
    {
        ///Increases the ID Key
        int IDVal = 7;

        ///Uses Connection String from DB to form local connection
        SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Chris\Documents\LogInFormMK2\LogInFormMK2\Students.mdf; Integrated Security = True");

        ///Opens Connection
        Connect.Open();

        ///Initialises the AddRecord 
        SqlCommand AddRecord = new SqlCommand();

        ///Sets all variables passed from main to a parameters to avoid SQl injection
        AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FirstName);
        AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", LastName);
        AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CWG", CurrentWorkingGrade);
        AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", PredictedGrade);
        AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", year);

        ///Creates the query
        AddRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.StudentINFO (Id, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, CurrentWorkingGrade, PredictedGrade, Year) VALUES (IDVal, + @FN, + @LN, '2001/05/21', + @CWG, + @PG, + @YR)");

        AddRecord.Connection = Connect;

        AddRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Student added succesfully");

        IDVal = IDVal + 1;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry there was an error adding this student. Error Code" + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
AddRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.StudentINFO (Id, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, CurrentWorkingGrade, PredictedGrade, Year) VALUES (IDVal, + @FN, + @LN, '2001/05/21', + @CWG, + @PG, + @YR)");
```

Should come before this:

```
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FirstName);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", LastName);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CWG", CurrentWorkingGrade);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", PredictedGrade);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", year);
```

Becoming:

```
///Creates the query
SqlCommand AddRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.StudentINFO (Id, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, CurrentWorkingGrade, PredictedGrade, Year) VALUES (IDVal, + @FN, + @LN, '2001/05/21', + @CWG, + @PG, + @YR)");

///Sets all variables passed from main to a parameters to avoid SQl injection
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FirstName);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", LastName);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CWG", CurrentWorkingGrade);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", PredictedGrade);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", year);
```

Answer (score 4):

You do this:

```
SqlCommand AddRecord = new SqlCommand();
```

Then you do this to declare and set your parameters:
<sub>(and btw: the AddWithValue() method is not the best way to use parameters)</sub>

```
///Sets all variables passed from main to a parameters to avoid SQl injection
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FirstName);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", LastName);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CWG", CurrentWorkingGrade);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PG", PredictedGrade);
AddRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", year);
```

Then you do this again:

```
AddRecord = new SqlCommand(...);
```

Note the **`new`** keyword... you have replaced your SqlCommand object with an entirely new object. This new object does not have any parameters declared.

You can fix this either by setting the `CommandText` property instead of re-creating the whole object, or by moving that line up above the parameter code, to combine it with the earlier variable declaration.

While I'm here, you should also think about what happens if an exception is thrown while executing your sql statement. In short, program execution will jump straight to the `catch` block and never call `Connect.Close()`... which you fail to do anyway. You should wrap your `SqlConnection` object in a `using` block to make sure the connection is closed properly, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you, what would be a better way to add a parameter? and why would it be better? Sorry im really new to SQL haha

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/